# How can I make the footerview always stay at the bottom in UITableViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am using a `UITableviewcontroller` and I want the **footer view** to always stay at the **bottom** of the screen. However, the `y` position of the **footer view** is changing as per the `height` of the `tableviewcell`. How can I always make it stick to the bottom of the screen?

Comment: Use tableFooterView property of table view

Comment: override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        if section == 1 {
            let footerView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.height - 40, tableView.frame.size.width, 40))
           
        return footerView
        }
        return UIView()
    }
This is actually my block of code. I want the footer at the bottom of the screen but it is not sticking at the bottom of the screen and keeps varying according to the height of tableview

Comment: Edited : =                                                                                                                            I dont think it was possible with uitableviewcontroller.. So what I did was added the view as a subview of navigation controller and it worked for me :)

Answer (score 7):

The `tableview` footer view would always stay at the bottom of the `tableview` and would always scroll with it. If you need to make the footer view fixed at the bottom then you can not use a `TableViewController`.You will have to use `UIViewController` , put your `tableView` as a subview. Put the footer also as another subview and its done.

Comment: I know it sounds stupid. But is it possible to add another a view in tableviewcontroller? Here m working on something for which I  have to use tableviewcontroller so can't switch to a view controller. I am trying to make it work :( is it possible to add any other view in tableviewcontroller class? And maybe make it stick to the bottom

Comment: If you are using a `UINavigationController`, you an add your `footerview` as a `subview` to your `navigationController`.  Don't forget to remove the `footerView` from `viewDidDisappear`, otherwise it'll appear with all of your screens in the navigation stack.

Answer (score 2):

A footer is always added to the bottom of the content size. So my approach is

**Approach 1: (Available for Both Static and Dynamic TableView)**

Add a `ViewController` in Storyboard and set your footer view(or button) at the bottom of the `ViewController`.

Add a `ContainerView` in the `ViewController` and set constraint

Add a `UITableViewController` and embedded the tableview in the container view

**Approach 2: (Available for both Dynamic TableView)**

Add a `ViewController`, set footer view in the bottom, add UITableView and set your auto layout.

You can't set static tableview in a UIViewController

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep footerview always at the bottom of the tableview without floating property like footer for section then can use

`tableView.tableFooterView = customFooterView`

Answer (score -1):

Override existing method of UiTableView

func allowsFooterViewToFloat() -> Bool {
return true
}

Answer (score -2):

Swift Code which make the footerView fill the rest space at the bottom,
then you can use autolayout to make you view at the bottom in the footerView:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews()
{
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()


    guard let footerView = tableView.tableFooterView else
    {
        return
    }

    var cellsHeight:CGFloat = tableView.tableHeaderView?.frame.height ?? 0

    let sections = self.numberOfSections(in: tableView)
    for section in 0..<sections
    {

        let rows = self.tableView(tableView, numberOfRowsInSection: section)

        for row in 0..<rows
        {
            let indexPath = IndexPath(item: row, section: section)
            cellsHeight += self.tableView(tableView, heightForRowAt: indexPath)
        }
    }

    var frame = footerView.frame

    frame.size.height = tableView.contentSize.height - cellsHeight;
    frame.origin.y = cellsHeight

    footerView.frame = frame
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You cannot use a `UITableViewController`, but it's not necessary anyway.  You can easily add a `UITableView` to a regular `UIViewController`, and just use auto layout to add a `UIView` below the `UITableView`.  Here's a simple example, adding a red `UIView` below the `UITableView`:

```
import UIKit

class MyFooterTableViewController: UIViewController {

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    var data = [ "One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven", "Eight", "Nine", "Ten", "Eleven", "Twelve", "One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven", "Eight", "Nine", "Ten", "Eleven", "Twelve"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.tableView.dataSource = self
    } 

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

}

extension MyFooterTableViewController: UITableViewDataSource {
    // MARK: - Table view data source

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return data.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TableCellTest", for: indexPath)

        cell.textLabel?.text = data[indexPath.row]
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = "BANANA"
        return cell
    }
}
```

The constraints on the Storyboard look like this:

[image: constraints]

The end result is this:

[image: animated]

Full project code is here:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/pyp42nzumquompp/TableViewFooter.zip?dl=0