# how to add a button to bottom of screen when using a uitableviewcontroller irrespective of number of rows?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

The requirement is that the button should be displayed sticking to the bottom of screen whether the table has 2 rows or 5 rows. If in any case, there should be a gap from the end of last row to the button at the bottom of the screen. How can this be achieved. Thank you.

Comment: instead of table view controller use table view, and add button as subview to bottom of screen.For gap i guess you need to place button on view controller view instead adding on table view.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I make the footerview always stay at the bottom in UITableViewController?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34610044/how-can-i-make-the-footerview-always-stay-at-the-bottom-in-uitableviewcontroller)

Answer (score 0):

You can't use UITableViewController. Use UIViewController and add table view on it. And add button below tableView. Add constraint to button, and stick it to superview bottom